# $.post returning 0 in value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm want to get a variable from Javascript to PHP via the POST function. I have tried to do something like this:

The problem line:

```
$.post(window.location, {idafevent: event.id});
```

Javascript:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
  element.bind('dblclick', function() {
    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
    $('#ModalEdit #medlemmerid').val(event.id);
    $('#ModalEdit #sletid').val(event.id);
    $.post(window.location, {idafevent: event.id});
    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
  });
},
```

My PHP:

```
$idafeventet = $_POST['idafevent'];
```

But the "idafeventet" is "0" when it shouldn't. Why is that?

Comment: What is the `event`. You are passing to `eventRender`?

Comment: My entire code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/K2A8UVFz

Comment: looks like u're passing eventRender and eventRender function takes 2 arguments. and your idafevent writing nowhere on js.

Comment: I'm sorry BMErER.. Could you explain a little bit more? I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Try a `console.log(event.id)`.

Comment: console.log(event.id) provides me with the correct ID. But it still dosen't work with the variable "idafeventet". That is still 0

Comment: Any ideas, AjAX or someone else?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the browser developer tool and make sure that form data when sending ajax request have contained "idafevent" input. Because I don't see any problem with PHP source code.

[image: Developer tools]